# JOptionPane choose

Tags: java

you can choose a different option when I click ok and another when I click cancel? If I have this kind of JOptionPane, if I can do that, how can I implement it?

```
   JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Message",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking

Comment: imagine you receive this JOptionPane with buttons ok and cancel my question is, if I press ok, you can do another action, and if I press cancel one another yet

Comment: if it is possible to choose,how can i implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the return value from the `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()` as an `int` and compare it to the constants available in `JOptionPane` to decide what to do next.

```
int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...);  
if(action == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){ // something }
```

**SSCCE:**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                int action = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                        "Click Something, Moron!",
                        "Y U NO Click!",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                if(action == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    System.out.println("YES!");
                }else if(action == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                    System.out.println("NO!");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("CANCEL!");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 For not being a cynical old, dried up husk, burnt out by a passionless industry so and so... ;)

Comment: -1 for not understanding what you just said xD Engleesh nut my lenguage, yew know xD

Comment: What I'm saying is you answer is nice and helpful, mine is little mean as it doesn't seem that the OP has done their homework first ;)

Answer (score 4):

You read the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> `public static int showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent,
>                       Object message)
>                                throws HeadlessException`
>
> Brings up a dialog with the options Yes, No and Cancel; with the
>   title, Select an Option.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `parentComponent` - determines the Frame in which the dialog is
>   displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default
>   Frame is used
>  `message` - the Object to display
>
> Returns:
>
> **an integer indicating the option selected by the user**

And when that fails to help you, you have a look at the tutorials, like [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for example

Comment: OMG here you are again to steal my rep points. I shall not let that happen ! NEVER ! xD

Comment: @LittleChild Nah, you answer is "nicer", I suspect the OP will like yours over mine...which is as it should be ;)

Comment: I added an SSCCE, just in case you decide to do some sleight of hand xD

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way.

```
 if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == 0){
        System.out.println("YES");
 //The value zero represents index of first option which will be the YES option
    }
else if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == 1){
        System.out.println("NO");
 //The value one represents index of second option which will be the NO option
    }
```

You can remove the index number and replace with the format you have so that it reads like this:

```
if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        System.out.println("YES");
 option
    }
else if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Bla bla", "Bla bla", JOptionPane) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        System.out.println("NO");
 option
    }
```

You can visit this YouTube link for more help [JOptionPane Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3NTQTOTNBM)